# Date query 14 days forwards and backwards

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a simple query but I would like to see 14 days forward and back with today's date. How can I do that?

The query is :

```
SELECT gut_pri as summe 
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll] 
WHERE masch_nr= 'FIMI3'
AND anmeld_dat = DATEADD(day, -0, convert(date, GETDATE()))
```

Thank you in advance.

Rene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT gut_pri as summe 
 FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_ade_protokoll] 
 WHERE masch_nr= 'FIMI3'
  and anmeld_dat BETWEEN DATEADD(DD,-14 GETDATE())AND DATEADD(DD,14 GETDATE())
```

Something like this ?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: But why `DD` and not `DAY`? One extra letter = [miles more readability](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).